# How to take a picture and uploading it with a comment to Flickr, Facebook, and Twitter?

Tags: camera, facebook, flickr

I am coming from the iPhone, and there was using an app called [Camera+](http://campl.us/), which worked well for my workflow. On Android, I am now looking for a way to:

1. On the go, *take pictures*, and store them somewhere. (I don't care where they are stored, they could very well be in a private store specific to the app.)
2. Allow me to go through the picture I took, delete the one I don't like, and for the others, *enter a description*, and upload them to a combination of Flickr, Facebook, and Twitter. I want to just enter the description *once*, click on checkboxes for Flickr, Facebook, and Twitter to select where the picture will go.

I could do this with the standard Camera/Gallery, with the Flickr and Facebook apps installed, but it requires way to many steps. I'm looking for something simple, that allows for a fast workflow, not for an editing workhouse. Is there any solution out there that would allow me to do this?

Comment: As questions like "Is there an app for X" are off topic (by our [FAQ]), I took the freedom to re-phrase it to prevent it from being removed. Hope you don't mind :) What you want is not necessarily an app -- you want a solution, right?

Comment: I don't know what you exactly meant by the *'description'*. Did you mean some sort of metadata (EXIF?) or renaming the file? Or just a body text for social sharing?

Comment: @Izzy I was unaware of that rule, and will keep it mind for the future. Thank you for rephrasing my question; your version indeed better reflects the question I really have :).

Comment: @Power-Inside Maybe I should have said "title" instead of "description", i.e. the main text that Flickr or  shows under or next the pictures. It may also be stored in the EXIF metadata, but this is not really the part I care about.

Comment: @avernet I thought so, so I happily adjusted it. Though my answer turned out to be an app: We prefer the question to be open to "home-made" solutions as well, if possible. Sometimes you'd be surprised what's possible without including an app :) (Well, basically apps are always included, if you count those belonging to the pre-installed system ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution doesn't require any app:

1. Upload pictures by email to Flickr. As a one-time setup, [find your private Flickr email address](http://www.flickr.com/account/uploadbyemail/) and I recommend you add it as a contact in Gmail. Then, from the Gallery, share by email, and send it to your Flickr email, optionally typing a description in the email subject.
2. Setup an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) rule to upload to Facebook pictures you send to Flickr. To make it simpler, you can reuse this [recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/69941).

Benefits:

- You're not relying on any third-party app, and can use the standard Android tools.
- You can queue images for upload (sorting, entering descriptions, deleting locally), even if you are offline, say abroad with no WiFi or data connectivity. The pictures will be queued in your email outbox and will be sent when you're back on the grid.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would in fact be using a specialized photo app: [Fotor for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ei.hdrphoto.en). Next to a bunch of features for taking and editing photos, the app description mentions:

> Using Fotor you can easily share your amazing photos with friends and family! Share photos via email, Facebook, Twitter and Flickr, with just one touch.

Which is exactly what you asked for. This app even supports HDR, and much more... So this would be your all-in-one solution. Seems hard to beat...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for Flickr but you can use applications like [Molome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hlpth.molome) or [Instagram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android) to quickly share photos on both Facebook and Twitter.